# Error after upgrading the Joomla site to Joomla 3.6

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

I am getting this error after upgrading my site to Joomla 3.6

It worked for few minutes then I started getting this error.
and this error is coming in both admin and site side.

## An error has occurred.

> 0 The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 2):

change the cache and the administrator/cache folders permission so that it can be writable by your web server.